# Can you win at level 8 in Munchkin?

Tags: munchkin

A friend played Munchkin Deluxe the other day and told me he won at level 8 when he killed a monster which granted 2 levels. To my understanding, I thought you NEED to kill at level 9 in order to win.

Can anyone explain if this is correct or not?

Comment: What made you believe that you need to be level 9?

Comment: Indeed, there's no such rule.

Comment: You can even win at level 7 (there are cards that add 1 level to the rewards of a defeated monster).

Comment: theoretically you can even win at level 1, although it's highly unlikely to happen

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games. Please check the mark next to the answer to accept it. If not, please identify your problem with it.

Answer (score 31):

From the [Munchkin Rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf):

> The first player to reach Level 10 wins . . . but you must reach Level 10 by
>   killing a monster, unless a card specifically allows you to win another way.

The only requirement it gives is that you kill a monster to reach Level 10, it doesn't say you have to be Level 9 when you kill it. The only other rules about winning say you can't reach Level 10 by selling loot or playing a Level Up card.

From the [Munchkin FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/):

> Note also that ANY level gained as a result of killing a monster counts as the winning level. If you have a Race or Class ability that lets you get an extra level after winning certain combats, that level can be the winning level.

This supports the idea that you don't have to be Level 9 when you kill a monster, you just have to get to Level 10 as a result of killing a monster.